# Unable to enumerate the process modules

Tags: vb.net, process, handle

I was trying to make a file unlocker which get process which using the file and get it killed to make it able to be deleted. It was okay when my targeted file is a WMP file. But I can't get it work when it comes to dll and iso. I got the problem on this line:

Which is used to get the process name. Any help is appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnShow.Click
  Dim files As New List(Of String)
  files.Add(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
  Dim Processes As List(Of Process) = Util.GetProcessesUsingFiles(files)
  RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbCrLf & "Processes that using the file is:")
  For Each p As Process In Processes
    TextBox1.Text = (Path.GetFileName(p.MainModule.FileName))
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(".exe", "")
  Next
  Timer1.Start()
End Sub
  Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnKill.Click
    If TextBox1.Text = ("Nothing") Then
        MsgBox("No proccess is using that file.")
    ElseIf MsgBox("Proccess(es) killed") Then
    End If
    For Each p As Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileName(TextBox1.Text))



        Try
            p.Kill()
            ' possibly with a timeout
            p.WaitForExit()
            ' process was terminating or can't be terminated - deal with it
        Catch winException As Win32Exception
            ' process has already exited - might be able to let this one go
        Catch invalidException As InvalidOperationException
        End Try
    Next
```

Comment: That line of code you posted, doesn't have to do that much with getting the process and kill it. What you have tried and researched?

Comment: That is just a single line of my code. I used this http://mdetras.com/2011/06/11/get-processes-locking-a-file-in-vb-net/.

Comment: We need a TL;DR version of the link you posted, in regard to your specific problem.

Comment: @Neolisk, do you mean the entire code?

Comment: Either that, or the part that's relevant to your question. Second option is preferable.

Comment: @Neolisk Updated. Check my question again. The Util class refer to the link.

Comment: Where is the line that does actually kill a process?

Comment: Updated. Check Button3_Click event. Thanks.

Comment: You retrieve the correct process list in the button1 click event, but you only use it to display them. In button3 click, you don't try to retrieve the processes with the correct method, but you are doing it completely different... Why not either "store" the list you received in the button1 click or just retrieve the list of processes again in the button3 click?

Comment: But my button 1 couldn't get the process name when it comes to DLL and ISO. So button 3 doesnt matter. I get the process into another textbox, so button3 get the process name from there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've already got the solution. Just add Try..Catch..